# Dynamic Loading based on combination of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a program where the user must select four parameters to view appropriate data. Each of these parameters have a defined list of possibilities. Currently each of these parameters has 6, 5, 3, 3 different possible input totals respectively. If you do the math that means there are 270 possible combinations of input, and many (but not all) will require different charts/graphs to be loaded. It looks a lot like *amazon* or *newegg*, in that they have a `treeview` with a variety of different options. The difference is the interface itself changes, not just the query. Obviously I can't manually create each combination, and even if I could at 270, its likely a fifth dataset will be added eventually.

What kind of design patterns exist for managing input combinations such as above?

**Edit**

Just for clarification If my input is `A6`, `B3`, `C1`, and `D2` then I would like to load something specific to that dynamically.

**Edit**

I was trying to keep it a little more general to avoid throwing in variables that add confusion, as they are industry specific. I'll make up four new ones for this.

```
Animals     Age Group    North American Country    Dataview
 Dog          All           Canada                   Historical
 Cat          Teen          U.S.                     Predicted
 etc
```

So If I chose Dogs owned by All age groups in the U.S. historically, then it should pull a set of charts and graphs the trend teenage dog owning, maybe because its dogs it might break it down by breed, and show the last twenty years of trends.

In this example changing country would barely be more than a query change, but changing `Dataview` or 'Animals' Might load a completely different set of graphs/charts. As mentioned earlier hardcoding in a lookup for each one is really not feasible, as there is a huge danger of a 5th and possible 6th column being required later. Also some of them won't change any time soon like North American Countries, but others could change.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? maybe give code examples?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that if you have parameters related to a given output would be to map this into a data structure, similar to a table in a database, where you can query the data you want to display given the parameters as where clauses

Comment: In the same venue I researched the factory design pattern. Your version scales better than that, but there has to be something better than 1:1 for each relationship (many of them are very similar)

My big concern is that if I have to add a 5th input variable (likely) and it is at all large that is over 1000 entries.

Comment: I didn't see your first comment, I don't have good code examples at this juncture, I've just got a big mess of trying to force nested messy case statements for a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest edit, I think this definitely seems like a job for a database, or failing that, a structure or set of structures that can be queried using something like linq.

Given my last answer, I think this seems like scenario 2 (where your parameters map absolutely to a specific set of data) or scenario 3 (where the parameters each relate to a piece of data, which once collected can be compiled into the desired result).

In terms of database structure (illustrated below), I would code this as follows:

```
[TABLE  : Parameters]
PK  : ParameterID
    : Parameter1
    : Parameter2
    : Parameter3
    : Parameter4
    : Parameter5
    : Parameter6

[TABLE  : Results]
PK  : ResultID
FK  : ParameterID [related to Parameters.ParameterID]
    : ResultData
```

You might query this as:

```
"SELECT ResultData FROM Results WHERE ParameterID = (SELECT ParameterID FROM Parameters WHERE Parameter1 = "" AND Parameter2 = "");
```

This way, you could map any combination of parameters to a unique result

You might even be able to do it another way:

```
[TABLE  : Results]
PK  : ResultID
    : ParameterHash
    : ResultData [possibility that this relates to other tables holding your results]
```

You might query this a slightly different way:

```
"SELECT ResultData from Results WHERE ParameterHash = '" + ComputeParameterHash(P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6); + "'";
```

Using a data structure such as this would not be affected by additional parameters being added in the future. Given my second table example, which uses a hash to resolve parameters to a result, any amount of parameters could be added to the hash calculator, producing a unique hash value for each data set. (beware of collisions). The first example would require more work because as you add more parameters, you will inevitably add more columns to the table. This should not affect existing records, but would require more work.

If your resulting data is spread across multiple tables, you might consider using views to concatenate data from different tables to deliver the desired result. For example: your parameters select data in a view, which in turn, pull data from the underlying tables that create the view, therefore you do not have to concern yourself with concatenating data together at code level from multiple tables. Your database can do that for you.

In terms of using design patterns, I would say, given your example, Entity Frameworks might be of some use in maintaining the relationship between relational data (in your database) and object oriented data (in your code).

Apologies if this is not at all what you are looking for, it's all I can think of right now. Consider this an abstract design based on a database structure, but can be modified to work with other data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Since not much is known about the actual problem, it is hard to come up with a definitive answer in this case, and I am unsure of any design patterns that will give the desired result, however to shed some theoretical light on possible solutions:

**Scenario 1 - An algorithm calculates the result given the parameter values, like a mathematical equation. I.E:**

```
(A6 + B3 + C1 + D2 = "Result 23")    
(A1 + B2 + C3 + D4 = "Result 119")
```

**Scenario 2 - The parameters form an absolute result. You may consider using a hash table or other similar data structure, where your parameters are hash mapped against the desired result. I.E**

```
(A6 + B3 + C1 = d0c423a2 = "Result 1")
(A2 + B5 + C4 = f6d33e56 = "Result 2")
(A3 + B4 + C1 = a34e6bbc = "Result 3")
```

**Scenario 3 - The parameters individually return a partial result which collectively return the desired result set. Again you can use a hash table. I.E.**

```
(A1 = cd3de456 = "Partial Result 1")
(A3 = d4e5ca23 = "Partial Result 2")
(B3 = b567d342 = "Partial Result 4")
(C1 = a34e6bbc = "Partial Result 66")
(D2 = f6d33e56 = "Partial Result 123")
```

*Therefore* `(A1 + B3 + C1 + D2 = "Partial Result 1", "Partial Result 4", "Partial Result 66", "Partial Result 123")`

If coded correctly, any of these could theoretically work, and lend themselves to the addition of additional future parameters.

Comment: This is in the right area. I'll explain a little bit more above with an edit and see what you think.